# Reiniciar serviço quando morto pelo sistema automaticamente

Tags: android

Eu estou utilizando um Service para realizar uma tarefa em background, quando eu starto ele por `startService()` e coloco no metodo `onStartCommand()`  `return START_STICKY;` ele reinicia sempre que o sistema força o fechamento da aplicação. Mas quando eu inicio esse mesmo serviço utilizando o `BindService()` ele não restarta o serviço automaticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite.

Então, como funciona os starts de serviços.

Caso você mande um `startService()`, ele será iniciado com a configuração do retorno do `onStartCommand()`

porém, se você iniciar via `BindService()` ele será um serviço preso a aquela classe, quando deixar de existir, ele será finalizado. por isso ele não passa por um `onStartCommand()`

Irei dar um exemplo na qual eu usei, para ver se fica melhor o entendimento.
Eu criei um MediaPlayer, que deveria ficar executando mesmo com a aplicação morta, semelhante ao GooglePlay Musica.

Ao selecionar uma música, eu dava um `startService()` no meu serviço de player e logo após um `bindService()` para poder atualizar o serviço através da aplicação, já que eu precisaria poder dar play, pause, etc... porém nem sempre eu estaria na tela do player, o player seria um extra da aplicação, se a pessoa abrisse o player, ele daria bind, senão, não teria conexão nenhuma com o player, logo, o serviço estaria vivo apenas pelo `startService()`